# Sharing Render to Bitmap image using Data Transfer Manager in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I want to share an image in my windows phone 8.1 application using DataTransferManager. 
For this I use my windows 8.1 app code for sharing using DataTransfer which works fine on Windows 8.1 but it doesnt work on WP8.1.

Here is my approach, I am converting my canvas into an image using RenderBitmap class then creating a RandomAccessStream of the bitmap to use in SetBitmap method.

```
   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView().DataRequested+= MainPage_DataRequested;
}

private async void MainPage_DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    var deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral();
    var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await bitmap.RenderAsync(canvas);

    // 1. Get the pixels
    IBuffer pixelBuffer = await bitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
    byte[] pixels = pixelBuffer.ToArray();

    // 2. Write the pixels to a InMemoryRandomAccessStream
    var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.BmpEncoderId, stream);

    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)bitmap.PixelHeight, 96, 96,
        pixels);

    await encoder.FlushAsync();
    stream.Seek(0);

    // 3. Share it
    args.Request.Data.SetBitmap(RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(stream));
    args.Request.Data.Properties.Description = "description";
    args.Request.Data.Properties.Title = "title";
    deferral.Complete();
}
```

This works fine in windows 8.1 how ever image not attaching in sharing apps like Messaging,OneNote etc in windows phone 8.1

[image]

[image]

Need help , Stuck here for a long time.

Comment: I think you should read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589448/sharing-from-windows-phone-8
It is the best answer for you right now.

Comment: Have a look at this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838278/sharing-render-to-bitmap-image-in-windows-phone-8-1

Comment: Finally solved it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838278/sharing-render-to-bitmap-image-in-windows-phone-8-1